# Jquery Coda Slider not working in Chrome, Works Pretty well in Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, coda-slider

I have used two Coda 2 Sliders at a single page and its working Fine with both the Firefox and IE 7,8,9. But i am not able to figure out why one of the slider is not working in Chrome while the other works

You can check yourself the live site at http://www.rafimmedia.com/siddiq/. As i have not used any php inside you can very well check the source code and css.

I even cross checked the syntax and everything and not able to figure out any problem. Tried to use firebug and even js has not shown any error.

Comment: I deleted my post because I didn't notice it was about the second slide.

Comment: Still i am waiting for an answer.. i dont think it is a tough question

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **rel** attribute the links for initiating the second set of sliders. Go to this page: http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/#3 and check out the Example #3.

Your first set of links and second set of links should include the rel="coda-slider-1" and rel="coda-slider-2" respectively.

Also, you need to make sure the links has a class attribute with the value "xtrig" to indicate they're cross links (again check the Example above).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <script>

$(document).ready(function ($) {
         $('div#slider1').codaSlider({
             autoSlide:true,
             autoHeight:false
         });
     });
</script>
```